# Change refresh interval for Openstack provider in CloudForms to run periodically

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, openstack, manageiq

I have a bug in CloudForms, related with broken targeted refresh for VMs. As a temporary solution I want to make a full refresh for the entire provider (OpenStack) running periodically, say every 30 minutes. I'm wondering how to do it on a production CF appliance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From CloudForms user point of view the easiest way to do it with advanced settings in WebUI.
Just put `:refresh_interval: 30.minutes` under the `:openstack:` section to override the common behavior of refreshing every 24 hrs. like this:

```
  :openstack:
    :refresh_interval: 30.minutes
    :is_admin: false
    ...
```